# Какой есть файловый менеджер аналог Mac Finder под Windows? C такой же многоуровневой иерархией папок (понятный скриншот внутри)

Tags: windows, mac, поиск-программ

Т.е. чтобы было видно содержимое "родительских" папок на несколько уровней вверх.

На скриншоте - обведенное красным

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://m.geektimes.ru/post/39503/

Comment: Могу посоветовать [One Commander](http://onecommander.com/), там есть подобный функционал.

Answer (score 2):

Могу посоветовать [One Commander](http://onecommander.com/), там есть подобный функционал.